# Reading file from SharePoint not returning correct value

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, csom

I am using the below code to read a file from sharepoint 2019 and the return values  are not string. Example of return values: 0\0\0(\u0001\0\0\u001e\0\0\0\0\0\0

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint2019/sites/test/"))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
            keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);                
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2})", resultRow["Title"], resultRow["Path"], resultRow["Write"]);

                File file= clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(resultRow["Path"].ToString());
                var stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                FileInformation fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream))
                {
                    // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                   String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }


            }

        }
```

Comment: Is there any updates ? Did you get the word content with Open XML SDK as suggested ?

Comment: Yes it worked correctly. Please find complete solution here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264061/read-content-of-a-file-and-display-the-result/264083?noredirect=1#comment280741_264083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading some files like Word (not txt file), you will need use Open Xml library to read the string in Word, filestream can't return the real string as expected:

[Get Plain Text of a Word Document using Open XML (CSOpenXmlGetPlainText)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3)

[Open a word processing document from a stream (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-a-word-processing-document-from-a-stream)

Comment: can you provide code that can open doc file without the interop library please